# libfreenect installation not building correctly with cmake

Tags: python, c++, cmake, openkinect, libfreenect2

This may sound basic but I am really struggling to get this all working and have been at it for hours I have tried following the installation process on [github](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) but this way of installing i am finding very confusing and all the tutorials I come across are either they are installing it on linux or its for libfreenect2 (i have the old 360 kinect camera). I have done all the driver stuff it says with zadig but I am falling at the cmake part of it as i just keep getting the error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (PROJECT):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried manually creating a CMakeLists.txt but I am also clueless on where to put it and what to put in it. Currently I have a directory as follows

```
kinect
|_ libfreenect
  |_ build

|_ libusb-1.0.26
   |_libusb
```

The command I am running is this which is what I believe I should be running i will add `-DBUILD_PYTHON3=ON` once I know cmake is working how it should be.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc -DLIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Users\hugow\Desktop\kinect\libusb-1.0.26\libusb\include" -DLIBUSB_1_LIBRARY="C:\Users\hugow\Desktop\kinect\libusb-1.0.26\libusb\libusb.lib"
```

I feel this is just due to my inexperience with cmake and the c language in general as this is my first time properly interacting with it.
I have all my gcc and g++ files in my path (thank you to ppl who answered my previous question :) ) however nothing seems to be building correctly and I am not even sure what the output should be. Ideally just a library that i can have in my `site-packages` folder in my python installation. I have only ever done python imports using pip so this is all really new to me and I have been at it for hours and seem to be getting nowhere. So any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It looks it tries to build with `nmake` - Microsoft toolchain utility, and fails to find it. If you want to build with msys toolchain you should probably at least run cmake with `-G "MSYS Makefiles"` so it would  build the code with msys `make` utility.